# UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight are reversed?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

The documentation says:

> `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`
>
> The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the right side.
>
> `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`
>
> The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the left side.

However, I'm getting them exactly reversed. Can there really be such a mistake in the SDK, or am I just going crazy?

Code:

```
+ (NSString *)NSStringFromUIInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)o
{
    switch (o) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait: return @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait";
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown: return @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown";
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft: return @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft";
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight: return @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight";
    }
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    NSLog(@"Should: %@", [[self class] NSStringFromUIInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation]);
    return YES;
}
```

I paste the above code in RootViewController.m of the default Navigation-based app template.

**Follow-up:** Reported as [bug 7216046](http://openradar.appspot.com/7216046).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Are you sure you're reading the docs correctly? Notice that the home button position and the orientation value are *opposites* - that is, `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` implies the home button on the *right* side, and `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` implies the home button on the *left* side. Make sure you're rotating your device to check properly.</strike>

**Edit:** I've confirmed the issue presented in the original question. Looks like a bug, unless I'm missing something too.

Comment: I am reading it correctly. I rotate the device clockwise and get UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft :/

Comment: What SDK version are you using?

Comment: Happens in both the simulator and on an iPhone, btw.

Comment: Same happens if I paste the above code in RootViewController.m of the default Navigation-based app template.

Comment: Hm. Is it possible for you to update to 3.1 on Snow Leopard? I'm in the process of doing so right now - if you can't, I'll be able to tell you in about a half hour whether this is an issue in 3.1.

Comment: OK, I've successfully reproduced your issue in Xcode 3.2/iPhone OS 3.1 GM on Snow Leopard. I've confirmed it in the docs, too. You may want to file a bug with Apple (and possibly post it on OpenRadar as well so other developers can follow the bug).

Comment: Done! Thanks for confirming I haven't gone mad :)